# Searching through a matrix in a specific pattern

Tags: r, function, matrix

I trying to do some fetching values in R. I am not an experienced programming.

I have a function  to search the matrix in an specific manner. This is the matrix:

```
k2=c(3,6,4,NA,NA,NA,NA)
k3=c(2,7,5,NA,NA,NA,NA)
k4=c(7,9,5,2,1,8,12)

df2=data.frame(k2,k3,k4)
m2=as.matrix(df2)
m2

     k2 k3 k4
[1,]  3  2  7
[2,]  6  7  9
[3,]  4  5  5
[4,]  NA NA  2
[5,]  NA NA  1
[6,]  NA NA  8
[7,]  NA NA 12
```

The main idea to find a value in the k4 row. If the value is not the same for that row,
the function should check the values in the same row, and go to these rows instead 
to find the value.

So if the value is less than val in [1,k4] then it should take the second column value in the same row ([1,k3])as the row number to go for and check the value in the third column in that row [value of row,3]. If the value is the greater, itshould do same thing as before, but with [1,k2]. And if the value is again not the needed one it should again check and repeat the same procedure for that next row until it gets the match.

Example :

So if I need val=5 then it should check if it is the same value as [1,k4] which is 7 and it is not, it should then go to third low check [3,k4] and as you can see it is the same, which means it is going to print 5. If I need the value I need is 12, then if should the logic be like this : the val is not the same as 7, so go to the third row, check with 9, oh its not the same value, the I will go to the 7 row, and there it is, its same val, I will print then...

**My code so far/My progress**

I know that I have to search the third every column time, so that means, beginning with the first

```
for (i in df2[1,3])
```

And then check if each value in that column is not equal to val:

```
if (!i == val)
```

And here comes the tricky part for me. I understand that I have to make a check if its less or greater, which means that is should somehow be like this

```
  if (!i == val) 
   #then check if its less, if yes, go that row
   #if it greater then go then go that row
   # go to that row and check the same thing there
```

And I do not know how to do that, so that it repeats itself for every row until it finds the value in val. I know that I can assing the row for smaller value as n-2 and the row for the bigger value as n-1, but I am strugling here to make it work. As I said, I have very little experience in programming.

Thanks a lot!

I really need help with this.

Comment: I can't follow your example. With `val = 5` you go to the first row, and then the third row and success! The third row has value 5. Then with `val = 12` you go to the first row, then you go to the third row and see value 9. Why not see 5 like the first time?

Comment: Also, in the start of your `for` loop, you have `for (i in df2[1, 3])`. But `df2[1, 3]` is a single value, it is 7. So your for loop only ever takes one value, `i = 7`. Is this correct? If not, what are all the values you will try to look for?

Comment: @Gregor

So if the val=12

1. Go to the first row and check the most right value in that row
2. The value is 7 and it not the same, then check which row I should go
3. To check to which row I should go, If I have to check if the value
is greater or less than 7
4. 12 is greater than 7, so I go to the second row
5. Check with 9, it is not the same as 12, again check if 
greater or smaller
6. It is bigger than 9, then I should go to row 7
7. The value is the same as 12

You dont see it because its like a "short cut"
8. Print the whole row with the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to re-state your problem so that we can be sure we're together.

We have a value to find, and a matrix to look through. The matrix is like a map: it gives directions. We start on the first row, and compare to the `k4` column.

- If the value is equal to the `k4` column on this row, we are done, success!
- If the value is less than the `k4` column on this row, go to the row number indicated by the `k2` column.
- If the value is greater than the `k4` column, go to the row number indicated by the `k3` column.
- Continue until there is a match.

As you say, it must "repeats itself for every row until it finds the value". Since we do not know how many repetitions, we must use a `while` loop, not a `for` loop. A `while` loop will keep trying until it is done. (This is dangerous because if it does not find an answer it will keep trying forever! So maybe we will put in a condition to stop if it tries too long.)

```
k2=c(3,6,4,NA,NA,NA,NA)
k3=c(2,7,5,NA,NA,NA,NA)
k4=c(7,9,5,2,1,8,12)

m2 = cbind(k2, k3, k4)

my_search = function(value, matrix) {
    current.row = 1
    try.counter = 1
    while(value != matrix[current.row, 3]) {
        if (value < matrix[current.row, 3]) {
            current.row = matrix[current.row, 1]
        }
        if (value > matrix[current.row, 3]) {
            current.row = matrix[current.row, 2]
        }

        # This is the condition to stop if we can't find an answer
        # To keep the algorithm from getting caught in a circle.
        if (try.counter > 1e6) stop("Couldn't find an answer :(")
        try.counter = try.counter + 1
    }
    cat(paste("The successful row number is", current.row, "\n"))
    cat("It's values are:\n")
    print(matrix[current.row, ])
}
```

Usage examples:

```
> my_search(12, m2)
k2 k3 k4 
NA NA 12 
> my_search(5, m2)
k2 k3 k4 
 4  5  5
```

If you want to be able to *assign* the output of the function, you should add another line to the function specifying what you want to return, e.g. `return(matrix[current.row, ])`.

Comment: Thats it!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I made a similar post, but for searching and deleting. Can you help with that? Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843853/deleting-or-adding-a-value-in-a-specific-pattern